# use laravel session value from function to another in the same controller in api or web route

Tags: laravel, session, redirect, cookies

When i'm trying to set session value in function then using this value it's fine but when i'm trying to reuse the same value which saved in the session with it's key i got undefined key in the  array of the session why that's happen and how to handle that i tried to set middleware in the route but it gave me the same error
note: i redirect from my domain to another domain i know that's the problem occur after redirecting how to handle that i need standard solution i used $_cookie and it's worked but i want to use session ???

I'm tring to use the session values from function to another in the same controller after redirecting to another domain and back to my domain can someone tell me how to handle that and you must know that i don't controll the response from the external domain and this domain don't return the data that i want ???
the question here i need session to not expired if i go to this domain then back to my domain ?

try to capture the id after the creation

```
public function setCaptureOrderId($id) {
    Session::put('catpureId', $id);
    Session::save();
    }
```

can use this getCaptureOrderId function

```
 public function getCaptureOrderId() {
    return $_SESSION['orderID'];
}
```

then  redirect

```
  public function http_create(){
      return Redirect::to($url);
    }
```

finally after the redirecting
getCaptureOrderId don't return anything and undefined key

Comment: show your code .....

Comment: i added some codes can help?

Comment: Laravel doesn't use PHP's native sessions, it uses its own ... you try to use `Session::get(...)` or the likes to retrieve the item you saved in the session  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#retrieving-data

Comment: doesn't work man i tried Session::get('')

Comment: i know what you are talking about but the session flashed after redirect to external domain

Comment: i solved that by using \Cookie:: but i want to use Session:: to hanlde that it's fail?